# Newly registered domain name, unable to access

Tags: domain-name-system

I recently registered a domain name, with a new site (found on HN), called EntryDNS (entrydns.net). For the sake of argument, call it theweb.com. I did this yesterday.

Today, to give their server ample time to get itself sorted, I tried to go to theweb.com, only to find that I cannot access it. I perform a dig command, and get the following information:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> theweb.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 51782
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;theweb.com.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
org.            887 IN  SOA a0.org.afilias-nst.info. noc.afilias-nst.info. 2010298277 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 30 12:35:14 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

I won't lie, I haven't a clue what that actually means. But I know for a fact I can't see my IP address in there anywhere. Here's the output after checking against EntryDNS's servers:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @ns1.entrydns.net theweb.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15513
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;theweb.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
theweb.com. 3600    IN  A   <<< EDIT: My IP address >>>

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 213.229.74.106#53(213.229.74.106)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 30 12:42:01 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

So, this leaves me with: normal DNS servers cannot see this record, but the EntryDNS servers can. I thought the whole point of running a public DNS server like this, is to let other people use the address theweb.com, rather than 192.168.0.1 (not my IP), to access my site. Why won't this work?

Edit: after running dig with +trace, I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> theweb.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           37985   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           37985   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4) in 32 ms

org.            172800  IN  NS  d0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            172800  IN  NS  a2.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  c0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  b2.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            172800  IN  NS  a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  b0.org.afilias-nst.org.
;; Received 435 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(i.root-servers.net) in 20 ms

org.            900 IN  SOA a0.org.afilias-nst.info.    noc.afilias-nst.info. 2010298451 1800 900 604800 86400
;; Received 96 bytes from 199.249.112.1#53(a2.org.afilias-nst.info) in 32 ms
```

Comment: It's up to you what you make public, but this sort of question is a **lot** easier to answer if you don't conceal the domain name in question.

Comment: It sounds like your forgot to tell your registrar what your DNS servers are.

Comment: So in the first query response shown, you asked for `theweb.com` and got back a response for `org`?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely your local recursive nameserver is caching the nonexistence of your domain.  This happens often when registering a new domain -- you start querying for it before it exists (because you're excited about a new domain, right?), and your nameserver caches the fact that it doesn't exist.  By the time it does exist, it's still serving the cached response.

While waiting for your local nameserver to forget that the domain doesn't exist, you can verify things are working using `dig +trace theweb.com` to ensure all the authoritative answers are working as expected.

Comment: The numbers 887 and 3600 in the output are the so called TTL values in seconds, they determine how long things will be *unconditionally* cached by downstream DNS servers. In the setup/test phase of a system, a value of 300 can save you a lot of nerves, set them to higher values to save DNS traffic later. The 887 is a computed value that is counted down by that server, when it reaches 0 information will be checked with upstream again - and the counter (p)reset to the TTL value from upstream (3600 here).

Answer (score 0):

Have you designated your name servers at your domain name Registrar? If not you need to do that first.

If so, then it looks to me like your name server information (nsX.entrydns.net) hasn't been updated at the parent servers (the gTLD servers) for your domain. Your domain name Registrar is responsible for updating the parent servers with your name server information so my suggestion would be to call them.